# What to present at SAML EntityID URL?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

I am trying to implement a SSO that is provided by another website.

The instructions ask me to enter "issuer" info. Which turns out is equivalent to the EntityID URL in the EntityDescriptor.

I am assuming I need to set that URL to some url on my server, but what I cant seem to figure out,  is what that URL actually does.

I assume a file needs to be placed at that URL with some information, but I can not seem to work out what that info is.

So what info is required at the EntityID URL in order for this to work?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The *requirement* is that the `EntityId` is a URI (not URL, in this case the difference between URIs and URLs is important). See "8.3.6 Entity Identifier" in the SAML2 Core spec.

From SAML 2.0 Specification :

> **8.3.6 Entity Identifier**
>
> **URI:** `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity`
>
> Indicates that the content of the element is the identifier of an
>   entity that provides SAML-based services (such as a SAML authority,
>   requester, or responder) or is a participant in SAML profiles (such as
>   a service provider supporting the browser SSO profile). Such an
>   identifier can be used in the  element to identify the issuer
>   of a SAML request, response, or assertion, or within the 
>   element to make assertions about system entities that can issue SAML
>   requests, responses, and assertions. It can also be used in other
>   elements and attributes whose purpose is to identify a system entity
>   in various protocol exchanges.
>
> The syntax of such an identifier is a URI of not more than 1024
>   characters in length. It is RECOMMENDED that a system entity use a URL
>   containing its own domain name to identify itself.
>
> The `NameQualifier` , `SPNameQualifier` , and `SPProvidedID` attributes MUST
>   be omitted

It is *recommended* that the URI is a URL that contains the domain name of the entity.

If you are to expose metadata, the EntityId is used as a well known URL for the meta data of the entity. It is not a requirement to provide meta data at all. If done, the meta data can be provided in any way possible - but the best practice is to publish it at the EntityId URL.

Comment: Is it permitted to use the `EntityId` URL like `metadata.xml` or should I map a URL pattern of `/metadata` to my metadata xml file ?

Comment: The EntityId should be a complete URL, that's all it says so `http://example.com/metadata.xml` should be fine.

Comment: Must this URI be registered somewhere ? What value does it present to the process ? How to verify the validity of this URI ?

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana The spec doesn't put any more requirements than that it must be an absolute URI. It doesn't have to be registered and if it's a URL it doesn't have to be to a registered DNS name.

Comment: Just some more details on `EntityId`: https://spaces.at.internet2.edu/display/federation/saml-metadata-entityid