# SSO with SAML 2.0 for wildcard domain

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I'm writing manually a federation metadata XML for “Relying Party Trust” and “Claims Provider Trusts” for ADFS 2.0
This could be a basic example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EntityDescriptor ID="_271f377f-78d8-4133-8c46-a73c4936bb1f" entityID="https://example.com" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
  <RoleDescriptor xsi:type="fed:ApplicationServiceType" xmlns:fed="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706" protocolSupportEnumeration="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/200706" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <fed:TargetScopes>
      <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsa:Address>https://example.com/</wsa:Address>
      </wsa:EndpointReference>
    </fed:TargetScopes>
    <fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint>
      <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsa:Address>https://example.com/</wsa:Address>
      </wsa:EndpointReference>
    </fed:PassiveRequestorEndpoint>
  </RoleDescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

There is some way to use something like wild carddomain to auth all my environments (development, integration, preproducction, production.. )

For example...

```
<EntityDescriptor ID="_271f377f-78d8-4133-8c46-a73c4936bb1f" entityID="https://*.example.com" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
        <wsa:Address>https://*.example.com/</wsa:Address>
```

to mach..

https://des.example.com/

https://int.example.com/

https://pre.example.com/

https://pro.example.com/

I already read [What to present at SAML EntityID URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196369/what-to-present-at-saml-entityid-url) but just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You *can not* use a wild card in the EntityID for a couple of reasons

- "*" is allowed [1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), [2](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) in a URI  but does not operate as a wildcard, so this wouldn't have the effect your are looking for
- Each Entity (identified by it's EntityID) should have its own endpoints so that other SAML Entities will now where to redirect browsers or issue backchannel requests to and/or where it should listen for requests.

You can simply copy the EntityDescriptor and change values for each of your environment